# C++ multi-thread memory leak issue

Tags: multithreading, gcc, memory-leaks, libc, libc++

Once the following code is running, it will eat all my memory and cause OOM issue on my ARM 64-bit processor.  it seems that some 'delete' operations do not work... it confused me. Could any experts help to analysis what is the root cause? Ttoolchain or libc?

I run the same code in another two platforms, one is x64, one is another ARM 32-bit chip; they all fine except my IPQ ARM chip.

**environment:**

- libc version: musl libc 1.1.16
- gcc version: 5.2.0
- cpu chip: IPQ ARM 64bit
- os: linux 4.1

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <list>
#include <memory>
#include <pthread.h>


void *h(void *param)
{
    while(1)
    {
        char *p = new char[4096];
        delete[] p;
    }
    return NULL;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv)
{
    pthread_t th[50];
    int thread_cnt = 2;
    for(int i = 0; i < thread_cnt; i++) 
        pthread_create(th+i, NULL, h, NULL);
        
    for(int i = 0; i < thread_cnt; i++) 
        pthread_join(th+i, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

1. If I use a mutex in the header-file thread callback, the issue will disappear; there is no memory leak.

```
std::mutex thlock;
void *h(void *param)
{
    while(1)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(thlock);
        char *p = new char[4096];
        delete[] p;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

2. If I change the memory allocation size to 1024, then a weird thing happed. 2 threads do not leak memory, but 20 threads will cause memory leak.  Whatever the allocation size, there's no issue with only 1 thread.

```
void *h(void *param)
{
    while(1)
    {
        //char *p = new char[4096];
        char *p = new char[1024];
        delete[] p;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

3. If I replace `new`/`delete` to `std::malloc`/`std::free`, the issue will disappear; no memory leak.

```
void *h(void *param)
{
    while(1)
    {
        //char *p = new char[4096];
        char *p = (char *)std::malloc(4096);
        std::free(p);
        //delete[] p;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

4. So I thought if I overload operator `new`/`delete` and my "`new`/`delete`" allocate memory by using `std::malloc`/`free`, maybe the issue could be solved. But
   the weird thing happened again; the memory leak still exists.

```
void* operator new(std::size_t sz) // no inline, required by [replacement.functions]/3
{
    std::printf("global op new called, size = %zu\n", sz);
    if (sz == 0)
        ++sz; // avoid std::malloc(0) which may return nullptr on success
 
    if (void *ptr = std::malloc(sz))
        return ptr;
 
    throw std::bad_alloc{}; // required by [new.delete.single]/3
}
void operator delete(void* ptr) noexcept
{
    std::puts("global op delete called");
    std::free(ptr);
}

void *h(void *param)
{
    while(1)
    {
        char *p = new char[4096];
        delete[] p;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

5. So I thought the memory leak may be caused by my operator `new`/`delete` rather than `malloc`/`free`, so I changed the code to look like what's shown below. I don't really call `malloc`/`free` but return a pre-allocated buffer. But the memory leak issue disappeared, so it seems the issue not only comes from new/delete...

```
char pp[4096];
void* operator new(std::size_t sz) // no inline, required by [replacement.functions]/3
{
    std::printf("global op new called, size = %zu\n", sz);
    if (sz == 0)
        ++sz; // avoid std::malloc(0) which may return nullptr on success
 
    return (void *)pp;
    //if (void *ptr = std::malloc(sz))
        //return ptr;
 
    throw std::bad_alloc{}; // required by [new.delete.single]/3
}
void operator delete(void* ptr) noexcept
{
    std::puts("global op delete called");
    //std::free(ptr);
}
```

So, what happened? Could any experts give me some idea? I guess it maybe caused musl libc thread lib; it seems that thread synchronization does not work fine... or is there a patch that already fixed this issue?

Comment: I wonder if you are seeing not a memory leak exactly but rather a problem with memory fragmentation.  Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62077590/why-can-a-user-process-invoke-the-linux-oom-killer-due-to-memory-fragmentation for a description of a possibly similar situation.

Comment: it seems not memory fragmentation issue, I try to  'echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/compact_memory', it not work for me

Comment: and actually, when OOM happens, there  really no free memory(eaten by this program, I checked by procrank ), I double checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this issue is involved by musl libc, and has been fixed by the following patch.

https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/commit/src/malloc?id=3e16313f8fe2ed143ae0267fd79d63014c24779f

above patch involved a buffur overflow issue of realloc and has been fixed by below 2 patches:

https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/commit/src/malloc?id=cb5babdc8d624a3e3e7bea0b4e28a677a2f2fc46
https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/commit/src/malloc?id=fca7428c096066482d8c3f52450810288e27515c